# What is the (best)name or description of this "method linking" to other components

Tags: java, design-patterns, naming-conventions, naming, method-chaining

First off, sorry for the strange "title", but since I don't know the name, it's quite tough to describe in a short sentence.

I've been here many-many times before, however this is my first actual activity.
I usually search, read and fight my way trough what I want to know. However, I just can't seem to get to my answer this time, which I find pitty.

Lately I've read "Head First Design Patterns", which I can't recall it was covered in there. Also I've hit quite some Google terms in the box, but without the correct defenition. I just can't find the right combination of search-words to nail the answer.

I've got a question about the correct name of "forward sharing / linking" 
of methods and their parameters.

I'm writing the JavaDocs comments to keep my code understandable, but I can't get the right term or Design Pattern name that fits to this.

But just asking this won't get me what I need i think. So I've got a little sample to demonstrate my question as BASIC as possible. I hope it is a bit understandable.

```
public class Framework()
{
    private Game game = new Game();

    public Framework()
    {
         loadComponents();
    }
    public void loadComponents()
    {
        // first loading framework requirements.. (lets say a button graphic)

        game.load();    // lets start loading the game....
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        new Framework();
    }
}

public class Game()
{
    private World world = new World();

    public void load()
    {
        // now we load some of the basic graphics.. (lets say a few borders)

        world.load(); // lets start loading the world!
    }
}

public class World()
{
    private Textures textures = new Textures();

    public void load()  
    {
        // now we load the worlds grid...

        textures.load(); // ofcourse we need textures, lets load...
    }
}

public class Textures()
{
    public void load()
    {
        // loading the textures...
        // end of this loading link.
    }
}
```

In this example we started off in the Framework, called the load method in Game, then called the load method in World, 
then called the load method in Textures. Lets make it a little simpler:

Framework.load()->Game.load()->World.load()->Texture.load();

But ofcourse we got more of these "links".

Framework.load()->Editor.load()->Entities.load();

Framework.input(Input input)->Game.input(Input input)->Player.input(Input input);

Framework.draw(Graphics2D g2d)->Game.draw(Graphics2D g2d)->World.draw(Graphics2D g2d);

How can I describe or call this "chaining/linking" the best? Becouse chaining in Java is like: Player.getLocation().setLocation(12,12).etc();

I hope my question is a little clear now,
thank you for your time in advance!

- Edwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is called the [Delegator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern)